# Subscript out of range error VBA when copying multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA function that I am using to copy of list of sheets from active workbook and save it. I am getting subscript out of range error. Any help would be appreciated?

```
Private Sub exporttoexcel(excelFileName)
excelFileName = 'File in my local'
Dim mySheetList() As String
Dim WS As Worksheets
Dim WB As Workbook
MsgBox excelFileName
'Dim sourceWB As Workbook
'Dim destWB As Workbook
'
'Set sourceWB = ActiveWorkbook
'sourceWB.Sheets.Copy
'
'Set WB = Workbooks(excelFileName)
    ReDim mySheetList(0 To (ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count) - 1)
     Dim a As Integer
      a = 0

      For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
          mySheetList(a) = WS.Name
          a = a + 1
       Next

Dim Fileobj
Set Fileobj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Fileobj.FileExists(excelFileName) Then
    Fileobj.DeleteFile excelFileName
End If

'     'actually save
     Worksheets(mySheetList).Copy '<<<<<<< RUN-TIME ERROR 9 RAISED HERE
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=excelFileName
     'MsgBox excelFileName

     'ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=excelFileName, FileFormat:=xlXMLSpreadsheet
     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))
     WB.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the error occurring? On what line?

Comment: Also see [run-time error 9: subscript out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/8917/vba-run-time-errors/27748/run-time-error-9-subscript-out-of-range#t=20170407145205001556) on documentation.SO.

Comment: `Dim WS As Worksheets` should be `Dim WS As Worksheet` - `Worksheets` is a collection class that doesn't have a `Name` property, so I'm not sure how your `For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheest` loop can iterate even once without blowing up with run-time error 13 / Type Mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have passed the sheet a list of names of sheets, i.e., "sheet1","sheet2",etc. However, when passing an array the function `Sheets(Array(mySheetList))` must be used.

```
'Worksheets(mySheetList).Copy
Sheets(Array(mySheetList)).Copy
```

Comment: Sorry about that. The error is in the Worksheets(mySheetList).Copy.

Comment: The `Worksheets` collection should be preferred to the `Sheets` collection whenever referring to *worksheets*. The `Sheets` collection can contain non-worksheet items, such as charts. Also OP's `mySheetList` is *already* an array of strings, so I'm not sure wrapping it in another array would actually help.

Comment: Yeah I just tested the code above and it works with your suggested change

Comment: @Lowpar - I tried that. But it still errors out with subscript out of range.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, I would try adapting somewhat for your excelfilename. There was also a problem with the ws being dimmed as a worksheet. I would use Option Explicit in the future.

```
Private Sub exporttoexcel()
'excelFileName = 'File in my local'
Dim mySheetList() As String
Dim WS
Dim WB As Workbook
MsgBox excelFileName
'Dim sourceWB As Workbook
'Dim destWB As Workbook
'
'Set sourceWB = ActiveWorkbook
'sourceWB.Sheets.Copy
'
'Set WB = Workbooks(excelFileName)
    ReDim mySheetList(0 To (ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count) - 1)
     Dim a As Integer
      a = 0

      For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
          mySheetList(a) = WS.Name
          a = a + 1
       Next

Dim Fileobj
Set Fileobj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Fileobj.FileExists(excelFileName) Then
    Fileobj.DeleteFile excelFileName
End If

'     'actually save
     Sheets(mySheetList).Copy
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=excelFileName
     'MsgBox excelFileName

     'ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=excelFileName, FileFormat:=xlXMLSpreadsheet
     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))
     WB.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Why leave `WS` an implicit `Variant` instead of declaring it as a `Worksheet`?

Comment: It was causing an error on my version. when I made it implicit it worked, usually I do not have this problem

Comment: Probably just because of a typo. You can definitely declare it as `Worksheet` - I just tested it myself. OP's `As Worksheets` throws a *type mismatch* error though.

Comment: @Lowpar - I get type mismatch error too as Mat's Mug

Comment: @Kavinathan what Excels are you using? I am on 2016.

Comment: Excel version 2007

Comment: I see. I am not sure if version could be the issue as the same code works in my colleagues machine who has version 2013. Just that the machine we use for running this script can't be upgraded to newer version

Comment: I am sure it could be modified to work, I would just need the correct version, either way, it's a small change, keep trying